# Can I get the dll Deleted by Visual Studio "Clean Solution" command?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I wrongly checked-in files which causes some important methods missing? I also mistakenly clean the solution. Is there is a way to get the dll which visual studio deleted during "clean solution" process? Means some where in temp files. It is not in recycle-bin.

Comment: Not unless you have some third-party software that can recover deleted files, or you use Windows 7/8 previous versions etc. Why not just check out the version before your mistake and rebuild?

Comment: No. The "Clean Solution" command *deletes* the file. It bypasses the Recycle Bin. And no sane implementation would move deleted files into the temporary folder.

Comment: @RogerRowland, the problem is that the methods were new before check-in. I got some conflicts and I mistakenly accepted changes. Means they were not available before.  BTW, can you tell me a specific third party software?

Comment: If the files were still there when you had a restore point created (e.g. by a windows update or virus check), you might find a previous version if you are configured suitably. [See here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/recover-lost-or-deleted-files) for details.